# django unsupported format character 'S' (0x53) at index 6 valueerror django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am getting a strange error when I try to save:

> unsupported format character 'S' (0x53) at index 6 valueerror django

This are my models:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)


class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %S" % (unicode(self.thread.id), self.body)
```

When I try to save a `Message`, it just gives me this error. Please help me solve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%S` is not valid. Use `%s` instead. And use a Unicode literal, since you're supposed to be returning a `unicode`.

```
return u'%s - %s' % ...
```

Comment: `%S` made me bang my head! Thank you so much!